# Update com base em um select

Tags: mysql

Tenho que atualizar o campo `custo` da tabela `pedidos` com base no campo `valor` da tabela `produtos_pedidos`.

Sendo que o `a.id` da tabela `pedidos` tem que ser igual ao campo `b.id_pedido` da tabela `produtos_pedidos`.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
UPDATE 
pedidos a
SET 
custo = (
    SELECT 
        b.valor
    FROM 
        produtos_pedidos b
    WHERE 
        b.id_pedido = a.id
    )
```

Estou tendo esse erro:

```
Coluna 'custo' não pode ser vazia
```

Comment: Esse é o update inteiro? pode ser o select retornou algum registro com null na coluna valor.

Comment: Provavelmente é isso que esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sugiro utilizar `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE 
    pedidos a
    INNER JOIN produtos_pedidos b on b.id_pedido = a.id
SET
    a.custo = b.valor
```

O problema no comando original na pergunta parece ser a existência de itens na tabela `pedidos` para os quais não há item correspondente na tabela `produtos_pedidos`. Então, para um pedido sem produto corresponente, ocorrerá erro. O `INNER JOIN` garantirá que somente pedidos com registro corresponente em `produtos_pedidos` serão obtidos para a atualização de custo.

P.s.: caso o campo custo não possa aceitar valores  nulos, você ainda pode utilizar uma função como `COALESCE` para substituir nulo por zero, ou incluir uma clausúla where para filtrar apenas quando os registros de `produtos_pedidos` tiverem valor.

Comment: se o campo custo não aceita valores nulo e no campo valor aceita o erro vai continuar acontecendo.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza bem lembrado, valeu.

Answer (score 3):

Pode acontecer dele não esta achando nenhum valor que bata com o a.id.

Tente assim:

```
UPDATE 
pedidos a
SET 
custo = (
    SELECT 
        coalesce(b.valor, 0)
    FROM 
        produtos_pedidos b
    WHERE 
        b.id_pedido = a.id
    )
```

onde o `coalesce(b.valor, 0)` retorna um valor padrão se for nulo, nesse caso coloquei 0

Comment: Da sua forma deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: tente colocar o coalesce no custo = coalesce (select)

Comment: não esta dando certo, olha o exemplo que eu fiz.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bdaef

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um valor default caso b.valor seja `null` ou verificar se o b.valor é `null`.

```
UPDATE 
pedidos a
SET 
custo = (
    SELECT 
        b.valor
    FROM 
        produtos_pedidos b
    WHERE 
        b.id_pedido = a.id
        and b.valor is not null
    )
```

Eu usaria uma query assim.

```
UPDATE a
SET custo = case when b.valor is null then 0 else  b.valor end
FROM pedidos a
join produtos_pedidos b
on b.id_pedido = a.id
```

Comment: Não deu certo de nenhum forma amigo. Na primeira continua o erro falando que o custo não pode ser nulo, e na segunda da um erro de sintaxe